# javascript: получить новый массив из старого массива с дополнительным параметром для каждого элемента

Tags: javascript, массивы, map

У меня есть массив элементов и каждый элемент обязательно содержит поле `value` и может содержать поле `id`

Требуется получить новый массив в котором у каждого элемента будет задано поле `id` и если оно не было задано у первоначального массива, то у нового должно равняться полю `value`.

Мой код:

```
let data_new = data_old.map(obj => {
    obj['id'] = obj['id'] || obj.value;
    return obj;
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста позволяет ли javascript делать более понятный, простой код с тем же функционалом?
А то может я микроскопом гвозди забиваю.

Можно ли в одну строку сделать такое преобразование?

Причем необходимо именно выполнить присваивание новой переменной, поэтому `forEach` как-то не очень подходит - опять же будет 2 команды: изменение старого массива и назначение его новому.

Comment: `dn=do.map(o=>Object.assign(o, {id: o.id||o.value}))`

Comment: Если бы объекты в массиве имели бы какой-нить недефолтный прототип, можно было бы впарить в цепочку прототип с геттером `{get id(){return this.value}}`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let data_old = [
  {id: 12, value: 34},
  {value: 56}
];
let data_new = data_old.map(obj => (obj.id = obj.id || obj.value, obj));
console.log(data_new);
```

Но Вы понимаете, конечно, что объекты в старом массиве тоже изменятся, так как это те же самые объекты.

---

```js
let data_old = [
  {id: 12, value: 34},
  {value: 56}
];
let data_new = data_old.map(obj => [obj.id = obj.id || obj.value, obj][1]);
console.log(data_new);
```

Comment: да, конечно понимаю, я же не клонирую данные, а поясните пожалуйста смысл строчки, не очень улавливаю конструкцию `(sub_element, element)`

Comment: появился вот такой ворнинг `Unexpected use of comma operator  no-sequences`

Comment: @Zhihar оператор "запятая" возвращает второй операнд

Comment: т.е. первый  блок (до запятой) - это то, что надо сделать, а второй блок (после запятой) - это то, что надо вернуть?

Comment: @Zhihar не обязательно два... в любом месте, где ожидается только одна строчка кода, но хочется пихнуть дополнительные выражения... даже какой-нибудь `let i = 1; if (console.log(i), alert(i), i > 0) alert("woohoo");` вычислит всё перечисленное, но вернет только последнее. С "запятой" код выглядит не очень очевидно, наверно потому и появился warning. Её любят те, кто занимается спортивным сокращением кода))

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME, понял, хитро :) но хотелось бы конечно без ворнинга решение (без отключения ворнингов) :)

Comment: @Zhihar Вариант из вопроса вполне уместный, если нет строгого условия делать одной строчкой... только `obj.id` вместо `['id']`

Answer (score 1):

Нашел еще один вариант решения без предупреждения `Unexpected use of comma operator  no-sequences`:

```
  let data_new = data_old.map(obj => ({...obj, 'id': obj['id'] || obj['value']}));

  console.log(data_new);
```

Comment: Этот код не делает то же самое, что тот.

Comment: @Igor, почему не то же самое, результат дает тот же? предложенный ниже вариант кстати не корректен, потому что работает только при 2х полях, а если полей 10? их все придется записывать

Comment: Потому что, как мы с Вами уже обсудили, тот код изменяет объекты из старого массива, а этот создает новые.

Comment: @Igor, понял, но так изменение первоначально объекта - это скажем так побочка и не всегда полезная :), зависит от ситуации конечно

Comment: если идти дальше: `data_old.map(({id, value,...rest}) => ({id:id||value, value, ...rest}))`

Comment: @Grundy, а какие преимущества перед `data_old.map(obj => ({...obj, id: obj.id || obj.value}))`? ведь даже подлиннее получается :)

Comment: Не переписываются одноименные свойства

Comment: @Grundy, но ведь это ни на что не влияет, `data_old` не меняется в моем примере, в вашем тоже