# Можно ли как-то сократить запись с map?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая тривиальная запись:

```
doc.files = doc.files.map((file) => {
    file.checked = value;
    return file;
});
```

Можно ли как-то сократить, чтобы не использовать скобочки?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Метод map() создаёт новый массив с результатом вызова указанной
> функции для каждого элемента массива.

В контексте этого кода, нет смысла в создании нового массива.

Правильнее сделать так:

```
doc.files.forEach((file) => file.checked = value);
```

Answer (score 3):

сам недавно задавал (и отвечал) на подобный вопрос
[javascript: получить новый массив из старого массива с дополнительным параметром для каждого элемента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1182522/javascript-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc)

Мой вариант (под ваше задачу), правда запись в новый массив

```
new_files = doc.files.map(file => ({...file, 'checked': value}));
```

Посмотрите по ссылке - там и другие варианты были

Comment: Стала короче запись? Нет. Стало читабельнее? Нет. Стало быстрее? Нет. Осталась логика неизменной? Нет.

Comment: Стала короче запись? `doc.files.map((file) => {file.checked = value; return file;});
` vs `doc.files.map(file => ({...file, 'checked': value}));` - думаю да. Стало быстрее? с каких javascript стал про скорость?  Если у нас обрабатываются массивы из 100-1000 элементов, то вопросы производительности тут вообще далеко не на первом месте будут, как интерпретатор разные коды будет обрабатывать - вопрос к разработчикам браузеров. Так что спорно. Осталась логика неизменной? Да, если под логикой понимать окончательный результат.

Comment: Единственное тут все упирается - автору надо в тот же массив и тогда действительно лучше использовать `foreach`, надо в другой массив - лучше использовать `map`. Опять же `Можно ли как-то сократить, чтобы не использовать скобочки?` - предложенный код не содержит `скобочки` как границы тела функции :)

Answer (score 2):

Вы модифицируете объекты в оригинальном массив и даже не сохраняете ссылку на старый список. В этом случае `map` не нужен.

```
doc.files.forEach(file => file.checked = value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно поизвращаться и сделать так. Но смысла в этом я не вижу.

```js
let files = [{
  a: 1
}, {
  a: 2
}];
const value = false;
files = files.map((file) => (file.checked = value, file));

console.log(files);
```